# Static IP configuration failed in NODEMCU

Tags: wifi, nodemcu, dhcp, static-ip-address, esp8266wifi

I'm trying to connect NODEMCU to my home network and set static IP address, but the static IP didn't set properly this is the code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.config(IPAddress(192,168,1,129), IPAddress(192,168,1,1), IPAddress(225,225,225,0));
  WiFi.begin("Bam", "123456789");
  Serial.print("\nConnecting");
  while(WiFi.status()!=3){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("Connected");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

and this is the output on the Serial monitor:

```
13:28:46.715 -> Connecting.......Connected
13:28:50.937 -> 192.168.1.100
```

when I set the same static IP address to my phone it sets with no problem.

I tried to config the IP before connecting to WIFI:

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
```

I tried to add delay before printing the local IP:

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
delay(2000);
WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
//loop to check if nodemcu is connected
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP);
```

I tried to disconnect and reconnect the WIFI I tried to disable the WIFI and start a new connection I tried to add the 4th and 5th argument which are DNS1 DNS2 none of these work for me.

I wanna see when printing the local IP the address I set to NODEMCU.

Comment: You should configurate the ip before you start the actual connection.

Comment: @Juraj I said I've tried everything even config first, I mentioned all solution I've tried in the question.

Comment: add `WiFi.disconnect();` after WiFi.mode. `mode` does `begin` with stored settings. add `WiFi.setAutoReconnect(false)` to disable that stored connection. add `WiFi.persistent(false)` to turn off storing the settings in flash memory

Comment: @Juraj didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me:

```
// Configures static IP address
  if (!WiFi.config(local_IP, gateway, subnet, primaryDNS, secondaryDNS)) {
    Serial.println("STA Failed to configure");
  }
  
  // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  // Print local IP address and start web server
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
```

You can find it on the articel here: `https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-nodemcu-static-fixed-ip-address-arduino/`